# convert elements of matrix into numeric from character

Tags: r, matrix

How can I change the class of numbers in the below matrix, "fruits" into numeric from character

```
> fruits
        June     July     August    September October  November December
Apple   "809936" "901956" "1311202" "1121499" "711812" "79647"  "0"     
Mango   "663300" "667529" "669158"  "664627"  "657280" "78982"  "0"     
Banana  "484458" "436396" "475879"  "496827"  "507660" "54120"  "0"
```

Comment: Just do `'dim<-'(as.numeric(fruits), dim(fruits))`

Comment: @akrun my numbers changed into numeric BUT I lost my headings

Comment: use the class as below. I will cancel my answer soon anyway.

Comment: Try this: `class(fruits) <- "numeric"`

Comment: @gitblame 's answer worked great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try, if `m` is your matrix:

```
`class<-`(m, 'numeric')
```

Comment: what are those backticks for? can you explain a bit what this does? Couldnt get it to work..

Comment: Instead of `class(m) <- "numeric"`, modifying the object you can have a functional approach `functionModifyingtheClass(m, "numeric")` where here, `functionModifyingtheClass` is `\`class<-\``